# Weird Spring Context Component Scan

Tags: java, spring

I found many solutions to lots of my queries already from stackoverflow and this is first time I am asking a question here and I don't really know what's wrong with that. Actually I am trying to Autowire one of my classes by type but unable to do that. Following is the source code in sequence.

> Spring Context

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

 <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
          p:location="/WEB-INF/mysqlConfig.properties" />

<bean id="sessionManager" class="com.bakaenterprise.dal.SessionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />

</bean>

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.bakaenterprise" />

<bean id="searchManager" class="com.bakaenterprise.bl.SearchManager" />

<bean id="fileDao" class="com.bakaenterprise.dal.impl.FileUploadDao" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="10" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="5" />
        <property name="maxWait" value="5000" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate Configuration -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:packagesToScan="com.bakaenterprise.beans">

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                    org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">
                    true
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">
                    true
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

#### interface

```
package com.bakaenterprise.dal;

import com.bakaenterprise.beans.FileUploadBean;
import com.bakaenterprise.core.base.GenericDao;

public interface IFileUploadDao extends GenericDao<FileUploadBean> {

}
```

#### implementation

```
package com.bakaenterprise.dal.impl;

    import com.bakaenterprise.beans.FileUploadBean;
    import com.bakaenterprise.core.base.HibernateDaoSupport;
    import com.bakaenterprise.dal.IFileUploadDao;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    /**
     * @author ali
     */
    @Component
    public class FileUploadDao extends HibernateDaoSupport<FileUploadBean> implements IFileUploadDao {

      @Override
      public boolean save(FileUploadBean obj) {
        super.save(obj);
          return true;
      }

      @Override
      public FileUploadBean getRecordById(Serializable id) {
        return super.getRecordById(id);
      }

      public boolean deleteRecordById(int id){
        return super.deleteById(id);
      }


      @Override
      public List<FileUploadBean> listAll() {
        return super.listAll();
      }

    }
```

#### Manager class

```
package com.bakaenterprise.bl;

package com.bakaenterprise.bl;

import com.bakaenterprise.dal.IFileUploadDao;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * @author ali
 */
@Component
public class TestManagerImpl implements ITestManager {
 @Autowired
    private IFileUploadDao fileDao;

    @Override
    public void test() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
@Override
    public IFileUploadDao getFileDao() {
        return fileDao;
    }
@Override
    public void setFileDao(IFileUploadDao fileDao) {
        this.fileDao = fileDao;
    }

}
```

#### Code where I am using Search Manager and testing FileUploadDao object is null or not

```
@Autowired
private ITestManager testManager;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        try {

            IFileUploadDao fileUploadDao = testManager.getFileDao();
            // now testManager is null

}
```

#### Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SearchServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.bakaenterprise.server.SearchServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SearchServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlets/SearchServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <jsp-config>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/jstl/core_rt</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/c.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/jstl/xml_rt</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/x_rt.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/jstl/fn_rt</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/fn.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
        <taglib>
            <taglib-uri>/jstl/fmt_rt</taglib-uri>
            <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/fmt.tld</taglib-location>
        </taglib>
    </jsp-config>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>performance</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.bakaenterprise.util.PerformanceLog</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>performance</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/springContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
   </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

> Now File Dao is always null, I think its not scanning the components though base package is correct. Any help or suggestion would be highly regarded and appreciated. And I know this type of question is being asked many times so apologizes for asking it again, those answer didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add depends-on attribute in your spring context configuration:

```
<bean id="searchManager" class="com.bakaenterprise.bl.SearchManager" 
      depends-on="fileDao" />
```

**EDIT:**

You `FileUploadDao` defined twice, one bean with `@Component` annotation and second with XML:

```
<bean id="fileDao" class="com.bakaenterprise.dal.impl.FileUploadDao" />
```

So, you just create two copies of one bean! And it's a problem I think.

**EDIT-2**

Try to remove this XML definitions:

```
<bean id="searchManager" class="com.bakaenterprise.bl.SearchManager" />

<bean id="fileDao" class="com.bakaenterprise.dal.impl.FileUploadDao" />
```

and add `@Component` annotation to `SearchManager`

**EDIT-3**

You need to autowire `SearchManager`:

```
  public SearchServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Autowired
    private SearchManager searchManager;

    public void init(ServletConfig config) {
      super.init(config);
      SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnServletContext(this,
        config.getServletContext());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just defining the bean in xml or using @Component should be enough.

Comment: I tried your suggested solution of adding depends-on attribute but that didn't work. I event tried with only @Component but same results

Comment: @AliAdnan: try without bean definitions inside XML

Comment: @seralex.vi I removed both of them from the XML but still its same. fileDao object is null. I also annotated SearchManager and FileUploadDao classes with Component annotation.

Comment: @AliAdnan: can you add your web.xml and code where you using SearchManager? And how you check that fileDao is null?

Comment: @seralex.vi Added, Please check it in actual question asked, i am debugging it to test if its null

Comment: @AliAdnan: "SearchManager manager = new SearchManager(request)" you just create new instance and not using Spring bean!

Comment: @seralex.vi Yes i updated the actual question, now manager object itself is null

Comment: @AliAdnan: where init(ServletConfig config) method that I wrote?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to declare this explicitly in applicationContext for the bean you want to autowire.

```
<bean id="searchManager" class="com.bakaenterprise.bl.SearchManager" autowire="byType"/>
```

An alternative is to autowire `byName`, which should work in your case too (since member variable`fileDao` has the same name as the bean ID `fileDao`).

Answer (score 2):

`SearchManager` should be annotated also for the `IFileUploadDao` implementation bean to be injected during the component scan

```
@Component
public class SearchManager {
```

Also you're initializing `SearchManager` manually which will result in its dependencies not being injected - The bean needs to be managed by `Spring`. As  there is no direct way to inject Spring Beans into a Java Servlet, you can use a Spring framework `HttpRequestHandler`.

```
public class AnnotatedHttpServletRequestHandler implements HttpRequestHandler {

   @Autowired
   private SearchManager searchManager;
   ...
}
```

Specific details are described in [Injecting Spring Beans into Java Servlets](http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2012/02/injecting-spring-beans-into-java-servlets/)

Comment: But SearchManager already declared with xml configuration and this annotation just override xml bean definition because bean id is searchManager. In other cases this create a duplicate bean.

Comment: Well, yeah, I would remove the explicit bean declaration in the XML and let the component scan do its magic

Comment: Explicit bean declaration is removed fro the XML but its still same, is there any problem with component scan? any extra step required.? As i still believe that its not scanning all classes.

Comment: Looks ok. can you add the package name to the `SearchManager` class above?

Comment: @Reimeus Added, Please check in the actual question asked.

Comment: Ensure you are not running the old code. Clean your project & rebuild. Also can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: @Reimeus: you can't autowire beans to Servlet. Special method call required to process injection to classes that are not Spring beans! See may answer

Answer (score 0):

You have some options here, you can annotate your class `SearchManager` with:

- `@Component`
- `@Configurable` - The @Configurable is used to mark a class eligible for Spring dependency injection. It's should be used when you can't or have no intention to use your class as a Spring Bean ***(Available since Spring 2.0)***

There are other ways to wire your classes, but you may lose some benefits.

You also should remove the xml declaration:

```
<bean id="searchManager" class="com.bakaenterprise.bl.SearchManager" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried both of them Component and Configurable. But situation is same. One more addition to the actual question that if i declare fileDao object static and provide its mapping in springContext.xml then the dependency is injected but not through component scan.

Comment: have you removed the xml declaration as was said?

Comment: Yes i did but still is same

Comment: where are you instantiating your SearchManager?

Comment: In a Servlet, i updated the actual question asked, please check it

Comment: you're instantiating your SearchManager using the ***new*** keyword, then it's not being managed by Spring e.g. Spring will not inject the FileUploadDao

Comment: you should use the ***@Configurable*** approach. If it's no working you should check your aspect configuration, it requires aspect to work.

Comment: @AliAdnan: I would use this approach, but i think the answer seralex.vi gave work as well.